Find the differential equation by its solution $y = c_1 \ln x+ c_2 e^x + c_3 \sin x.$
This is a problem of my exam, all my class failed and tried it again later and we gave up; sorry if this doesn't fit in this forum.

Find the differential equation by its solution
$$y = c_1 \ln x+ c_2 e^x + c_3 \sin x.$$

Note: my teacher gave us a hint; use $\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1$.
Edit: sorry for not explaining myself, I asked for the differential equation which must not contain constants, this is done by differentiating the same number of times as there are constants and using different mathematical techniques to add or subtract the derivatives or/and the given equation itself in order to eliminate the constants if any were left after differentiating.
We only differentiate three times and then we don't know what else to do because we can't eliminate $c_1$, and it was the only question of the exam. I'm in third semester of BME.

Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Welcome to MSE. Can you outline the strategies you tried and where they went wrong? Context matters for questions and so far all we have is an excerpt from an exam. What level was the exam?

sorry for not explaining myself, i asked for the differential equation which must not contain constants, this is done by deriv, rentiate the same number of times as there are constants and using different mathematical techniques to add or subtract the derivatives or/and the given equation itself in order to eliminate the constants if any were left after differentiate, thank you for your time sir.

yes, we only differentiate three times and then we dont what else to do because we cant eliminate $ c_1 $, and it whats the only question of the exam, im in third semester of BME

@ Juan: You must find the three functions $a(x),b(x),c(x)$ such that $\ln$, $\exp$, and $\sin$ satisfy
$$y'''+ay''+by'+cy=0.$$
Just substitute and solve (but I cannot see how the hint was useful). @RolandF: I don't understand your comment.

@AnneBauval From what I've learned, not exactly. The method that was teached to me was first differentiate the given function as many times as there are constants. Then, do some "magic" to eliminate the remaining constants, like multiplying the first derivative by -2 and add it to the third derivative in order to eliminate one or more constants. And none of my class understood the hint. Thank you for helping me and editing the post.

From $y=c_1\ln x+c_2 e^x+c_3\sin x$, differentiate $3$ times to get a system
of equations linear in $c_1,c_2,c_3$:
$$
{\frac {{\rm d}^{3}}{{\rm d}{x}^{3}}}y \left( x \right) =2\,{
\frac {{\it c_1}}{{x}^{3}}}+{\it c_2}\,{{\rm e}^{x}}-{\it c_3}\,\cos
 \left( x \right) ,\\
{\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{x}^{2}}}y \left( x
 \right) =-{\frac {{\it c_1}}{{x}^{2}}}+{\it c_2}\,{{\rm e}^{x}}-{\it c_3
}\,\sin \left( x \right) ,\\
{\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}y \left( x \right) 
={\frac {{\it c_1}}{x}}+{\it c_2}\,{{\rm e}^{x}}+{\it c_3}\,\cos \left( x
 \right) ,\\
y \left( x \right) ={\it c_1}\,\ln  \left( x \right) +{\it c_2
}\,{{\rm e}^{x}}+{\it c_3}\,\sin \left( x \right)
$$
Then eliminate $c_1,c_2,c_3$.  For example Gaussian elimination.  Maple gets
$$
 \left( \cos \left( x \right) \ln  \left( x \right) {x}^{3}+\ln 
 \left( x \right) \sin \left( x \right) {x}^{3}-2\,{x}^{2}\sin \left( 
x \right) +\cos \left( x \right) x-\sin \left( x \right) x \right) {
\frac {{\rm d}^{3}}{{\rm d}{x}^{3}}}y \left( x \right) \\
+ \left( -2\,
\cos \left( x \right) \ln  \left( x \right) {x}^{3}+{x}^{2}\cos
 \left( x \right) +{x}^{2}\sin \left( x \right) +2\,\cos \left( x
 \right) -2\,\sin \left( x \right)  \right) {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{
{\rm d}{x}^{2}}}y \left( x \right) \\
+ \left( \cos \left( x \right) \ln 
 \left( x \right) {x}^{3}-\ln  \left( x \right) \sin \left( x \right) 
{x}^{3}+\cos \left( x \right) x+\sin \left( x \right) x+4\,\sin
 \left( x \right)  \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}y \left( x
 \right) \\
+ \left( -{x}^{2}\cos \left( x \right) +{x}^{2}\sin \left( x
 \right) -2\,\cos \left( x \right) x-2\,\cos \left( x \right) -2\,\sin
 \left( x \right)  \right) y \left( x \right) = 0
$$

Rewriting
$$ y=c_1y_1+c_2y_2+c_3y_3,y’=c_1y_1’+c_2y_2’+c_3y_3’,y’’=c_1y_1’’+c_2y_2’’+c_3y_3”y’’’=c_1y_1’’’+c_2y_2’’’+c_3y_3’’’$$
as
\begin{eqnarray}
c_1y_1+c_2y_2+c_3y_3-y=0,\\
c_1y_1’+c_2y_2’+c_3y_3’-y’=0,\\
c_1y_1’’+c_2y_2’’+c_3y_3”-y’’=0,\\
c_1y_1’’’+c_2y_2’’’+c_3y_3’’’-y’’’=0,
\end{eqnarray}
one has
$$ \left|\begin{matrix}
y_1&y_2&y_3&-y\\
y_1’&y_2’&y_3’&-y’\\
y_1’’&y_2’’&y_3’’&-y’’\\
y_1’’’&y_2’’’&y_3’’’&-y’’’
\end{matrix}\right|=0.$$
Plugging in $y_1=\ln x, y_2=e^x, y_3=\sin x$ and expanding the determinant will give the desired DE.

A nice feature of this determinantal form is that expanding by cofactors along the RH column yields the coefficients in the ODE as matrix minors.

Here:
$$y=c_1\ln x+c_2 e^x+c_3\sin x$$
$$y'=\frac {c_1}x+c_2e^x+c_3\cos x$$
$$y''=-\frac{c_1}{x^2}+c_2e^x-c_3\sin x$$
Add $y$ and $y''$ to get:
$$y+y''=c_1\left(\ln x-\frac1{x^2}\right)+2c_2e^x$$
$$c_1=\frac{y+y''-2c_2e^x}{\left(\ln x+\frac1{x^2}\right)}\cdots\cdots(i)$$
Again, multiply $x$ with $y''$ and add with $y'$ to obtain:
$$y'+xy''=c_2e^x(1+x)+c_3(\cos x-x\sin x)$$
$$c_3=\frac{y'+xy''-c_2e^x(1+x)}{\cos x-\sin x}\cdots\cdots(ii)$$
And moreover, we have something more, we can find:
$$c_3\cos x=y'-\frac {c_1}x-c_2e^x$$
$$-c_3\sin x=y''+\frac{c_1}{x^2}-c_2e^x$$
Squaring and adding the terms we get:
$$c_3^2=\left(y'-\frac {c_1}x-c_2e^x\right)^2+\left(y''+\frac{c_1}{x^2}-c_2e^x\right)^2$$
Plug in the values of $c_3$ and $c_1$ from equations (i) and (ii) in here. I do not know if you can express $c_2$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ and its derivative only. But I would not elongate my answer.
Finding $c_2$ in terms of $x$ and $y$, find $c_1$ and $c_3$ too and put all those values in the equation of $y''$ to finish your answer.

Denote the solutions $$f_1(x) := \log x, \qquad f_2(x) := \exp x, \qquad f_3(x) := \sin x .$$
Then, the determinant
$$\det \pmatrix{y & f_1 & f_2 & f_3 \\ y' & f_1' & f_2' & f_3' \\ y'' & f_1'' & f_2'' & f_3'' \\ y''' & f_1''' & f_2''' & f_3'''}$$
vanishes (for all $x$) if and only if the rows are linearly dependent (over $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$), which in turn happens exactly when $y$ is a (real or complex) linear combination of $f_1, f_2, f_3$, that is, has the form $c_1 f_1 + c_2 f_2 + c_3 f_3$, but setting the determinant to zero gives a third-order, homogeneous linear differential equation in $y$.
Expanding the determinant (and multiplying the equation through by $x^3 e^{-x}$, which doesn't affect the solution space but yields a cleaner form) gives
$$0 = (x^3 (\sin x + \cos x) \log x - 2 x^2 \sin x + x (\cos x - \sin x) ) y'''(x) + \cdots .$$
Remark One can produce a higher-order but more compact differential equation for which all of the given linear combinations vanish by also asking that linear combinations of $f_1, f_2, f_3$, $f_4(x) := \exp(-x), f_5(x) := \cos x$ are solutions. Following the same procedure as before gives a $5$th-order differential equation:
$$\det\pmatrix{y & f_1 & \cdots & f_5 \\ y' & f_1' & \cdots & f_5' \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ y^{(5)} & f_1^{(5)} & \cdots & f_5^{(5)}} = 0 .$$
Multiplying through by $8 x^5$ and rearranging gives
$$0 = (x^5 \log x + 6 x) [y^{(5)}(x) - y'(x)] - (x^4 - 24) [y^{(4)}(x) - y(x)]$$
